# Fixing my code to prevent sql injection

Tags: postgresql, database-design, windows, c#, sql-injection

I made a login with authentication in DotNet windows forms app and I'm trying to do my best to guard the database from SQL injection attacks, but it seems like there was a wrong logic in my code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
/* -UNSAFE command-
            sql = @"SELECT employee_no FROM public.tb_userlogin where
            username ='" + Convert.ToString(userText.Text) + "' AND password ='" + Convert.ToString(passText.Text) + "'";
            */

            conn.Open();
            sql = "SELECT employee_no FROM public.tb_userlogin where username = _username AND Decoypass = _password";

            EmpNo = code.Converter_string(sql).ToString();
            cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_username", userText.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_password", passText.Text);

            if (userText.Text == String.Empty || passText.Text == String.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Field cannot be empty!");
            }

            if (EmpNo != "0")//log in successfully
            {
                this.Hide();
                new ClientCrudFrm().Show();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please check your username or password", "Login Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                return;
            }
            if (conTable.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("login successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message,
                "Something went wrong", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            conn.Close();
        }
```

`
This is the full code inside the login button:

```
 private void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //user login authentication
    {
        bool userValidated = validateUserInput(userText.Text);
        bool passValidated = validateUserInput(passText.Text);

        if (userValidated && passValidated)
        {
            getConnection();
        }
        
        try
        {
            NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Host=localhost;Database=UserLogin;Username=postgres;Password=adminAdmin1");

            NpgsqlDataAdapter conDataAdapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
            //NpgsqlDataAdapter conDataAdapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("select * from public.tb_userlogin where username='" + userText.Text + "'and password='" + passText.Text + "'", conn);
            DataTable conTable = new DataTable();
            conDataAdapter.Fill(conTable);

            /* -UNSAFE command-
            sql = @"SELECT employee_no FROM public.tb_userlogin where
            username ='" + Convert.ToString(userText.Text) + "' AND password ='" + Convert.ToString(passText.Text) + "'";
            */

            string username = userText.Text;
            string password = passText.Text;

            conn.Open();
            conDataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM public.tb_userlogin where username = $username AND password = $password", conn);

            EmpNo = code.Converter_string(sql).ToString();
            

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$username", userText.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$username", passText.Text);
            NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (userText.Text == String.Empty || passText.Text == String.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Field cannot be empty!");
            }

            if (EmpNo != "0")//log in successfully
            {
                this.Hide();
                new ClientCrudFrm().Show();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please check your username or password", "Login Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                return;
            }
            if (conTable.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("login successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message,
                "Something went wrong", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

with the updated code above, here saying a new error when I log in:

```
"The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling Fill"
```

Comment: Placeholders start with $ or @, not with _.

Comment: Thank you, I tried both prefix $ and : it says syntax error at near"$". While prefix @, error says operator does not exist: @ character varying. Anyway I'm using Postgresql database.

Comment: Can you please update your code to use the @ prefix? That should work. You should add it in the SQL CommandText, but don't need to do it in the AddWithValue. Or go with positional placeholders ($1, $2) as suggested below.

Comment: Injection isn't the only issue. It's very much NOT OKAY to just store the bare password in a column.

Answer (score 0):

From: [the Npgsql documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html), use `$1`, `$2`, etc. as the placeholders for your parameters, something like this:

```
sql = "SELECT employee_no"
    + "FROM public.tb_userlogin"
    + "where username = $1"
    + "AND Decoypass = $2"
    ;
```

Comment: Quite resolved but when I am bout to log in here saying: 08P01 bind message supply 0 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 2

Comment: If you use positional parameters ($1, $2), then don't define a name on your parameters when adding them. If this doesn't work, please post the full code.

Comment: I will show you the code inside the login button, I made some changes.